# Dimension of singular locus in reduced local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $(R, {\mathfrak m})$ is a reduced local Noetherian ring with $\dim R = d$, why is the dimension of singular locus of $R$ is strictly less than $d$?

I know that $$ \text{dim Sing} R = \text{sup} \{\text{dim} ~ R/\mathfrak{p} ~~| \mathfrak{p} \in \text{Sing} R \}  $$ and $$ \text{Sing} R =\{\mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec R} ~~ |~~ R_{\mathfrak{p}} ~\text{is not a regular local ring}\}; $$ and that a typical ring is reduced iff $ \cap_{\mathfrak{p} \in Spec R} \mathfrak{p} = \{0\} $, but can not reach any relationship between these informations.

Any help would be thanked.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07P6

Comment: I have seen this page before. But did not help.

Comment: Can you show that the localization of $R$ at any of the minimal primes is regular, thus showing they do not belong to the singular set?

Comment: It did not work. The problem is in step one.